# In Nixpkgs, what makes a python derivation an application rather than a library?

Tags: python, nix, nixpkgs

I'm trying to package a python application for Nix, but I'm finding that the majority of the documentation assumes that I want to package a library.

In order to do this, I looked at Rednotebook example (not for any particular reason other than I happened to know it was written in python), which can be found in [python-packages](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/e249d6e8ce627e24ff2880350007a218fcf7b269/pkgs/top-level/python-packages.nix), but as that file is so huge, here is the relevant part:

```
  redNotebook = buildPythonPackage rec {
    name = "rednotebook-1.8.1";

    src = pkgs.fetchurl {
      url = "mirror://sourceforge/rednotebook/${name}.tar.gz";
      sha256 = "00b7s4xpqpxsbzjvjx9qsx5d84m9pvn383c5di1nsfh35pig0rzn";
    };

    # no tests available
    doCheck = false;

    propagatedBuildInputs = with self; [ pygtk pywebkitgtk pyyaml chardet ];

    meta = {
      homepage = http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/index.html;
      description = "A modern journal that includes a calendar navigation, customizable templates, export functionality and word clouds";
      license = licenses.gpl2;
      maintainers = with maintainers; [ tstrobel ];
    };
  };
```

My derivation looks like this:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
let
  requirements = import ./nix/requirements.nix { inherit pkgs; };
in
pkgs.python35Packages.buildPythonPackage rec {
  name = "package-name";
  version = "1.0.0";
  namePrefix = "";
  src = ./.;
  doCheck = false;
  propagatedBuildInputs = builtins.attrValues requirements.packages;
}
```

`requirements.nix` was the output of `pypi2nix` and `requirements.packages` has type "list of derivations". Despite this when I cd into the resulting store path for Rednotebook there is a `/bin` directory with some wrapper scripts. The store path for my app there is just a `lib` an no `/bin`

How do I tell Nixpkgs that I have an application?

Answer (score 2):

There are [buildPythonPackage](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/interpreters/python/build-python-package.nix) and [buildPythonApplication](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/top-level/python-packages.nix#L55) functions, but at the end of the day, they both call [mkPythonDerivation](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/interpreters/python/mk-python-derivation.nix).

A Python application with a simple Nix package you can reference is [Ranger](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/f5fa5fa4d629a0dbc8033d86f1d5c6b2eb531f96/pkgs/applications/misc/ranger/default.nix); which uses `buildPythonApplication`. The resulting derivation contains a wrapper in `/nix/store/PACKAGE/bin/`

Comment: The main difference is that `buildPythonApplication` doesn't add the interpreter version to the resulting output name apparently.

Answer (score 2):

Was experimenting with building and installing a sample service written in Python.
Ended up using `buildPythonApplication` in my installer

### Important points

If you are leveraging `setuptools` to distribute your app you need to have the `entry_points` value in your `setup` call:

```py
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
...
entry_points = {
  'console_scripts': ['sample_module = src.app:main']
}
```

**src** - source code folder
**app** - entry point module name
**main** - name of the entry point function

My whole build configuration was:

```
# sample.nix
with (import <nixpkgs> {});
python37.pkgs.buildPythonApplication rec {
    pname = "sample_service";
    version = "0.0.3";
    src = ./sample_package;
    meta = with lib; {
        homepage = "https://www.example.com";
        description = "Sample Python Service";
    };
}
```

**sample_package** was the folder that contained 'src' folder and 'setup.py' located at the same level as above 'sample.nix' file.
At this point, if you run `nix-build sample.nix` it will build and install the package for you. However, to make it available on the path you will need to capture the resulting path in the nix store and run:

```sh
nix-env -i <nix_store_path>
```

Comment: This is an intermediate step to building a service. I omitted those elements for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

`buildPythonPackage` is to be used for libraries, that is, when you want it to expose its modules in `site-packages`. `buildPythonApplication` is for applications that just happen to be written in Python. In that case, when you include such a derivation in another derivation, you don't want to expose the libraries.

This separation is important because it may happen that a Python 3 environment calls a tool that is written in Python 2 and vice versa.

Note that at the time of writing this issue hasn't been completely solved yet, but at least `python.buildEnv` or `python.withPackages` will not include applications along with their dependencies.